# How to get actor's primitive component

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am trying to disable an actor's physics using Blueprints. I know I can do this with Set Simulate Physics, but this function requires a Primitive 
 Component. Currently I have the actor object reference, I am looking for a function that allows me to get the Primitive Component. Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for? Here is a capture of the code: https://ibb.co/C9n90Zd

If you need more info I will be happy provide it to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get Component By Class is the name of the function.

Comment: And to add some nuance (at least for me) - the nodes `Component Class` is set to `Primitive Component` and not `Actor Component`.  Now that seems completely obvious, but it wasn't for the last hour.

Answer (score 0):

If the actor can Simulate Physics, then the Root Component is a Primitive Component. The Root Component (GetRootComponent) is set for every actor; it’s either at the top of the hierarchy on the Blueprint editor, set explicitly in C++ code, or set arbitrarily by the engine from a collection of C++ components. You can check at runtime using IsSubclassOf if needed.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, is helpfull for learn those things. However the specific function that solves my problem was to use Get Component By Class.